# Path unspecified in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python

Running

```
/usr/bin/python "c:\Users\owner\Documents\GitHub\ud120-projects\tools\startup.py"
```

The system cannot find the path specified.

I can access the .py and edit it and all, but I can't run it?

What is the issue?

Comment: Are you using a terminal?

Comment: no, I am not using a terminal

Comment: Then how are you running your program?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using code-runner to run your python script and your path to python is not /usr/bin/python. The 0.9.0 update added support to shebang, which is overriding your executorMap configuration. Fortunatly, the 0.9.1 update added an option to ignore the shebang settings, which you can find in user settings. Change
`"code-runner.respectShebang": true`
to
`"code-runner.respectShebang": false` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought the solution would be so simple, but this worked. Thank you!

In case anyone has trouble setting that preference:
1. in Visual Studio Code, press CTRL + , (comma) to open preferences
2. In the User Settings panel (should be on the right), enter the line that @steve mentioned. Make sure it's comma-separated
3. Save the file and try again. Worked immediately for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you can't run it, it's that Python cannot find it.
Check:

```
import os
# Access a particular environment variable
# check based on OS, notes below:
# os.name The name of the operating system dependent module imported.
# The following names have currently been registered:
# 'posix', 'nt', 'mac', 'os2', 'ce', 'java', 'riscos'.
if os.name == 'nt':
    print(os.environ['Path'])
else:
    print(os.environ['HOME'])
print('*----------------------------------*')
print(os.environ['PATH'])
print('*----------------------------------*')
```

Comment: I ran this and both print out the same result, what does this mean?

Comment: it maybe that setup.py has a shebang pointing to /usr/bin/python which probably doesn't exist on your system as it looks like you're using NT platform (i.e. Windows) ... so remove shebang so that you can invoke setup.py from wherever your Python interpreter is installed.  

shebang == https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)